# Weird re-alignment on hover state

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have a Cloud of items which have all a hover state.

```
:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  border: 1px solid #333333;
}
```

but upon hovering all the other items get a weird re-alignment which switches back if hover is not triggered.

I tried making he padding bigger but it's still the same.

What am i missing here.

-----> http://jsfiddle.net/mMGAU/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that the new border makes the element 2px wider. You can solve it like this:

```
champs-tag-card {
    padding: 1px;
}

.champs-tag-card:hover {
    padding: 0;
}
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/DdvjP/)

As an alternative: You could also set the border-color to transparent in the "normal" state.

Answer (score 2):

On hover you add a `1px` border which is not there normally.  This causes your element to grow by 2px in both width and height.  This causes your other elements to re-align accordingly.

You could place an initial 1px transparent border on your elements so they do not resize when the border is set.

```
.champs-tag-card {
    border: 1px solid transparent;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mMGAU/11/

Answer (score 0):

**`border`** is increasing the width so go with **`outline`** property.

```
.champs-tag-card:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    outline: 1px solid #333333;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/mMGAU/7/)

Comment: Nice suggestion, but what about the radius?

Comment: Ow, but the outline changes the effect... don't fit the photo.

Comment: @ExplosionPills I missed it. I agree, mine is a bad solution

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
border:1px solid transparent;
```

to `.champs-tag-card`. The border takes up space, and this is causing the re-alignment.